# CFA: scaling of measured variables/indicators

Tags: correlation, standardization, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I'm running a latent variable analysis with:

- 166 observations
- 21 continuous variables
- using the R package `lavaan`

A simple run of `cfa()` function with on factor failed because of the **high range of variances** (from 3e-6 to 2e-1).

My first reaction was to standardise the dataset using the `z-score` and it worked.

**Question**: since the cfa is looking at reproducing a covariance matrix, doesn't it biase the analysis to have all variables variance equal to one?

**NB**: to tackle the issue I've also looked at:

- running it on a dataset scaled using the `min-max` method, the optimizer can't find a solution;
- using the cfa function with the correlation matrix obtained from the raw dataset as input (`sample.cov` and `sample.nobs` as explained by Beaujean (2014)) and it gives striclty the same result as the analysis that considers the standardised dataset.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have some variables with different scales. I searched on Mplus Discussion forums and apparently, they standardise continuous variables (transformation to z score) prior to modelling.
see: http://www.statmodel.com/discussion/messages/9/2090.html?1515716898

Answer (score 1):

Standardizing your 21 observed variables does not "bias" your results, though it does change how the results, particularly factor loadings, are interpreted. Standardizing observed variables can, however, help with convergence, as large and/or small (unstandardized) variances can cause numerical issues in estimation.

Comment: Or small variances too.

Comment: @Jeremy Miles thanks for the note!